# Canonical form of a quadratic form

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the canonical form of $2x^2+y^2+3y=0$

What are the way to approach this?

I know that the eigenvalues are positive and that

$$2x^2+y^2+3y=0\iff2x^2+(y+\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{9}{4}=0$$

For: $x'=2x$, $y'=y+\frac{3}{2}$

We get: $$x'^2+y'^2-\frac{9}{4}=0$$

How do I categorize this quadratic form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed the equation

$$2x^2+y^2+3y=0\tag{1}$$

is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
2x^{2}+\left[ y-\left( -\frac{3}{2}\right) \right] ^{2}-\left( \frac{3}{2}
\right) ^{2}=0.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Dividing by $(3/2)^2 $ and writting $2$ as $1/(\sqrt{2}/2)^2$, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^{2}}{\left( \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}}+\frac{\left[ y-\left( -\frac{3}{2}\right) \right] ^{2}}{\left( \frac{3}{2}\right) ^{2}}=1,\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
which is the [equation of the shifted ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation_of_a_shifted_ellipse) centered at $\left( h,k\right)
=\left( 0,-\frac{3}{2}\right) $ and semiaxes $a=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2}$ and $ b=\frac{3}{2}>a$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\left( x-h\right) ^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{\left( y-k\right) ^{2}}{b^{2}}=1.\tag{4}
\end{equation*}

$\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad$ [image]

*Comments*:

1. The [general equation of a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form) is
   \begin{equation*}
   Ax^{2}+Bxy+Cy^{2}+Dx+Ey+F=0
   \end{equation*}
   [If $B^{2}-4AC<0$, the conic is an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant). Equation $(1)$ is the particular case
   \begin{equation*}
   A=2,\quad C=1,\quad E=3,\quad B=D=F=0;
   \end{equation*}
   with $B^{2}-4AC=-4\times 2\times 1=-8<0$.
2. You only get 
   $$x'^2+y'^2-\frac{9}{4}=0$$
   for $x'=\sqrt{2}x$, $y'=y+\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: What it the best way to remember this? in 2D and 3D case? the conditions on the coefficients? or the get to the canonical form?

Comment: @gbox in 2D  you are dealing with [conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section): circumferences, ellipses, hyperbolas and parabolas, while in 3D, with [quadric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric), such as spheres, ellipsoids, hyperboloids and paraboloids. The most general Cartesian equation of a quadric is of the form $$Ax^2+By^2+Cz+Dxy+Exz+Fyz+Gx+Hy+Iz+K=0.$$

Comment: @gbox  In a book written in Portuguese I have, the discussion of the different cases is made, using homogeneous coordinates and the (symmetric) discriminant matrix whose determinant is the discriminant of the quadric.

Comment: Correction: $Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2+Dxy+Exz+Fyz+Gx+Hy+Iz+K=0$.